Pass Date Slicer Value on a Calculated Column
I am trying to get a past date pending case count from a live database, based on the Date selected in the slicer. But what I have is not a daily snapshot to know what was the past status, but a live database. For example, a case might be closed yesterday which was created last month. Since that case was pending and not closed as of last month end, when I select a Date slicer as Last month, I want that case to be counted as Pending even when it got closed as of date. Similarly, as and when I chose the Date slicer, I would like to see the pendency status basis Date Slicer and not as of date.
Is this possible in Power BI? Any support to solve this issue will be of tremendous help.
Thanks a lot in advance.
When I select a Date slicer, Cases pending as of Date Selection should give a count and not as per the current status. So, if something was pending in the past, it should show as Pending when the Date was selected.
